# Getting error with Stripe: No such payment_intent: 'my payment intent id'

Tags: c#, reactjs, stripe-payments, http-status-code-404

sorry I'm pretty new to coding so I don't know many of the abbreviations/shorthand stuff.
So I'm working with React and C# trying to use Stripe to handle payments and I've gotten to the point where I am getting back a `payment_intent id`, `client_secret`, and payment method Id, but when I run the code:

```
const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(this.state.clientSecret, {
      payment_method: paymentMethodRQ.paymentMethod.id,
    });
```

I get the error:

> No such payment_intent. Which is a 404 for the /v1/payment_intent/confirm

I guess that means the payment intent isn't actually being created since it doesn't show up on the Stripe dashboard either. Not really sure how to fix this. Most of the other similar questions either use different languages or don't address how to solve my particular issue. I followed the documentation for collecting payments then paying out, found at https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide#setup

This is my React code for the submit:

```js
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { stripe, elements } = this.props;

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      _logger("Stripe.js has not yet loaded.");
      // Make  sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return;
    }
    const paymentMethodRQ = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
    });

    const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(this.state.clientSecret, {
      payment_method: paymentMethodRQ.paymentMethod.id,
    });

    if (result.error) {
      toast.error("payment not processed");
      _logger(result.error.message, "payment not processed");
    } else {
      toast.success("The payment processing!");
      if (result.paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
        _logger("payument successful");
        // havent gotten to this part yet
      }
    }
  };
```

I am passing in an amount and currency for the `PaymentIntentCreateOptions` from *React*.
and this is my controller for the payment intent in *Visual Studio*:

```cs
[HttpPost("paymentintent")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PaymentIntent(PaymentIntentCreateOptions options)
        {
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "my test secret key";

            ItemResponse<PaymentIntentModel> response = new ItemResponse<PaymentIntentModel>();
            var service = new PaymentIntentService();
            var paymentIntent = service.Create(options);

            Logger.LogInformation(paymentIntent.ToString());

            var paymentIntentModel = new PaymentIntentModel();
            paymentIntentModel.Id = paymentIntent.Id;
            paymentIntentModel.ClientSecretKey = paymentIntent.ClientSecret;
            response.Item = paymentIntentModel;

            return Ok200(response);
        }
```

Comment: "No such..." errors are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account. I'd double check that your secret and publishable keys are for the same account.

Comment: @PaulAsjes wow I must've made a different account at some point because copying my keys and re-pasting them actually solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make sure that your public key you declare in the frontend matches your public key in your stripe account otherwise you will get this error.

Comment: Yeah someone else mentioned that as well a while back, I should have closed the question haha. Thanks for responding though!